# Index of subgroups of real vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, abelian-groups

> Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb R$ and $B=(u_1,...,u_n)$ and $C=(w_1,...,w_n)$ two bases of $V$, such that 
>   $$
> \begin{pmatrix}
> w_1 & \cdots & w_n
> \end{pmatrix}
> =\begin{pmatrix}
> u_1 & \cdots & u_n
> \end{pmatrix} A
> $$
>   for some $A \in GL_n \mathbb Z$. Let $U,W$ be the subgroups of $(V,+)$ generated by $B,C$ (respectively). Then $W$ is a subgroup of $U$ and $[U:W]= |\det A|$.

The first part is not difficult at all: $W\subseteq U$ (since its elements are sums of elements of $U$) and $W$ is itself a group. So $W \le U$. The second part is where I'm stuck. I know that there exists the formula 
$$[U:W] = \frac{\mathrm{Vol}\,W}{\mathrm{Vol}\,U}$$
but the purpose of this lemma is to prove that. So, I would avoid using it.

**Edit**. Let
$$D_W = \biggl\{ \sum_i t_i w_i : t_i \in [0,1)\biggr\}$$
This is a fundamental domain for the translation (that is, every point in $V$ can be written uniquely as $v+w$ with $v \in D_W, w \in W$. Then 
$$[U:W] = |\{u+W : u \in U\}| = |\{u+W : u \in U \cap D_W\}| = |U \cap D_W|$$
since $u+W= u'+W$ iff $u-u' \in W$ iff $u=u'$. This means that the index is the number of points of $U$ in $D_W$. Is this going to help?

Comment: I suppose you want $|\det A|$ instead of $\det A$.

Comment: Yes. I'll correct it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the case that $A$ is an elementary matrix (i.e., differs from the identity matrix by one entry $\ne1$ on the diagonal, or differs from the identity matrix by an off-diagonal $1$, or is a permutation matrix)

Comment: I'm not sure I can understand your hint... When $A$ is a permutation matrix, the index doesn't change and that's obvious. When $A$ is $I_n$ with a 1 changed with a $m$, then the index is multiplied by $m$, and that's ok. But I can't see how to show that the index is preserved when $A$ is $I_n$ plus an off-diagonal element...

Comment: @Human Note that such a matrix has an obvious inverse in $GL_n(\Bbb Z)$. Hence also $U\subseteq W$